# Web view click : url not detected in android , iOS working : react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, url, webview

I have a react native app which loads in a url in web view after login. The user moves in the web view clicking links as supported. Now I want to open share options from inside the web view by clicking on a button in the web view. When we click on the button, we have a url but I am unable to detect that url with 'onNavigationStateChange'. So how can we handle this without the url? I have tried many links, but none gets me the result. The 'OPEN SHARE CONTROLLER' is never reached, neither does 'navigation type click'. Here is my sample code:

```
 <WebView scalesPageToFit
    style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{ uri: url  }} onLoadStart={() => (setLoading(true))} onLoadEnd={() => (setLoading(false))}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    onNavigationStateChange = {handleNavigationStateChange}
    
    onLoadProgress = {({ nativeEvent }) => {
     
      console.log(nativeEvent.url)     
  }}
    />

const handleNavigationStateChange = navState => {
console.log(navState.url);
console.log(navState.navigationType)
const { url } = navState.url;
if (!url) return;

if (url.includes('Logout')) {
  Alert.alert(
    "Logout",
    "Are you sure you want to logout?",
    [
      {
        text: "No",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
        style: "cancel"
      },
      { text: "Yes", onPress: () => navigation.pop(1) }
    ]
  );
}
if (url.includes('Register')) {
  console.log('OPEN SHARE CONTROLLER')
}
if (navState.navigationType === 'click') {
  // User clicked something
  console.log('User clicked something')
```

}
};

Comment: `onNavigationStateChange` is called when the url of the web view changed, what is the action of your button?

Comment: The url changes but is not detected here as when I do the same thing with native iOS - using Xcode, I get the url and I open the share activity controller.

Comment: could you mind sharing more code of your web page? you may hide the sensitive details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by using `setSupportMultipleWindows={false}` and using onShouldStartLoadWithRequest.

Comment: what's the logic you applied in onShouldStartLoadWithRequest?

Comment: @Habibi27, I'm sharing my code for your reference 
```onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {
if (event.url.includes('Register')) {
              webViewRef.current.stopLoading();
              setLoading(false);
              Share.open({
                title: "A",
                message: message,
                subject: "B",
              })
              .then(result => console.log(result))
              .catch(errorMsg => console.log(errorMsg));
              return false
            }
             else {
              return true
            }
          }}

Comment: thanks @Preetika